# How to find out which form I want to alter

Tags: commerce, forms

I am adding a functionality to drupal commerce kickstart, which involves product display modification. There should be a lot of forms but I don't which one to alter and add my new object to the existed form. Any good idea? (There is almost no documentation about it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I usually do it is just implement `hook_form_alter` and inside put `dpm($form_id);`. Reload the page and it will echo all form ID's. You should find the one you want pretty easily, you can then change the `hook_form_alter` into a `hook_form_FORM_ID_alter`.

Answer (score -1):

You can find form_id by looking in the HTML of your site with firebug. Forms have their own id.
For example the form to add a article-node has this:

```
<form id="article-node-form" class="node-form node-article-form" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post" action="/node/add/article" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

So the form name is article-node-form. So check the html for the forms you want to alter for a  element.

Comment: That's not the Drupal `form_id` it's the CSS ID. You should check the hidden `form_id` element in the form markup instead. e.g: `<input type="hidden" name="form_id" value="apachesolr_panels_search_block">`

Comment: My bad. Thought cssid was always the same as the formid.